# Auto completion in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

In XCode 3.2.2 completion works whenever it chooses to.

One time it will, one time it won't.
Is there some flag or add-on to increase the auto-completion success rate ???

Is there maybe a better code editor that can link to xcode in a good manner which has better coding capabilities then XCode ?

Thanks

Comment: I too felt the autocomplete was acting weird with the recent updates, but you wouldn't want to go with some other IDE just for that reason. You can't doubt Xcode's coding capabilities. Its great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know. Maybe it depends on the way you code but it works for me most of the time. There is some case that it will not work, for example, too much complicated like `[[self.a doB] doC];`

Can you post me some code that it doesn't work for you?

Comment: Lets say I import CoreLocation,

When I try to autocomplete CLLocationManger it just won't.
Is this regular behaviour ?

Comment: it is really strange because it doesn't happen to me. I just tested it with XCode 3.2.2

Comment: Yee , quite annoying. Guess i'll have to settle with what I have.

I'll update it if an update will turns up, maybe it will get fixed somehow.

Thansk anyway.

Comment: yeah, I think something wrong with your XCode, good luck on next update:)